# I need help working with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a big dataframe of items which is simplified as below. I am looking for good way to find the the item(A, B, C) in each row which is repeated more than or equal to 2 times.
for example in row1 it is A and in row2 result is B.

simplified df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','B','A','A','C'],
               'C2':['B','A','A','C','B'],
               'C3':['A','B','A','C','C']}, 
              index =['ro1','ro2','ro3','ro4','ro5']                            
             )
```

Comment: What should it output if you have A/B/C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mozway suggested, we don't know what will be your output. I will assume you need a list.

You can try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd 
from collections import Counter

holder = []
for index in range(len(df)):
    temp = Counter(df.iloc[index,:].values)
    holder.append(','.join([key for key,value in temp.items() if value >= 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have three columns **and always a non unique**, you can conveniently use `mode`.

```
df.mode(1)[0]
```

Output:

```
ro1    A
ro2    B
ro3    A
ro4    C
ro5    C
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If you might have all unique values (e.g. A/B/C), you need to check that the mode is not unique:

```
m = df.mode(1)[0]
m2 = df.eq(m, axis=0).sum(1).le(1)
m.mask(m2)
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Anything wrong with it?